# Reading from _OUTPUT_connect

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In SAS DI when I connect a user written transformation to an output table, the variable _OUTPUT_connect is assigned. In my case it looks something like this:

```
%let _OUTPUT_connect =  DEFER=YES READBUFF=25000 DBCLIENT_MAX_BYTES=1 DB_LENGTH_SEMANTICS_BYTE=NO PATH=MY_PATH AUTHDOMAIN="MY_AUTH_DOMAIN"
```

Now I'm trying to extract the `PATH` and `AUTHDOMAIN` variables from `_OUTPUT_connect`. My solution for now is the following:

```
%let _authdomain = %sysfunc(scan(&_OUTPUT_connect,7," "));
%let _path = %sysfunc(scan(%sysfunc(scan(&_OUTPUT_connect,5," ")),2,"="));
```

This works but it breaks if the order of the `_OUTPUT_connect` variables changes.

I thought I'd use regex to match the paramater values: `PATH=[match_this]` and `AUTHDOMAIN="[match_this]"`, but I have problems parsing the variable `_OUTPUT_connect` because it contains double quotes. When I manually assign `_OUTPUT_connect` without the double quotes I can do the following

```
data _null_;
  re = prxparse('/PATH=(\w)*/');
  string = "&_OUTPUT_connect";
  position = prxmatch(re, string);
  put position=;
  matched_pattern=prxposn(re, 0, string); 
  put matched_pattern=;
run;
```

Output:

```
position=75
matched_pattern=PATH=A1091211_SAS_SRV
```

The problem however is that `_OUTPUT_connect` contains double quotes, and the regex function fails when the input string contains double quotes. Since `_OUTPUT_connect` is assigned automatically, I cannot change the format.
I've tried to remove the double quotes from `_OUTPUT_connect` using this `%let unquoted =%sysfunc(translate(%quote(&test),' ','"'));`. This does work, but it puts a whitespace in place of the double quotes.

Is there an easy way to retrieve the values of `PATH` and `AUTHDOMAIN` from `_OUTPUT_connect`?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the name value pairs of the connection string by using `SCAN` with modifiers.

Example:

```
data nvps(label='name value pairs' keep=name value);
  s = 'name1=value1 name2="value2" name3="value 3"';

  do index = 1 to countw(s,' ','q');
    nvp = scan(s,index,' ','q');
    name  = scan(nvp,1,'=','q');
    value = scan(nvp,2,'=','q');
    output;
  end;
run;
```

[image]